# Does "Much of the work towards this end" sound natural?

Tags: word-usage

Would the following sentence sound natural to native speaker? If not, what would be the modificiation?

```
Much of the work towards this end focused on [some concept].
```

Comment: Could you clarify the sentence a bit more? The sentence feels contrived, but I can't really say how I would modify it to make it feel more natural.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The example By @Gary in his answer brings some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would establish the **context** and then refer to it in the sentence.  For example:

"Our goal was the eradication of malaria in the county.  Much of the work towards this end focused on field drainage."

Answer (score 2):

The idiom here is often "toward these ends", given that you usually do not know how things might turn out -- there still might be ending points you do not foresee.  One's goals are generally 'ends', as opposed to 'means', but a single one of them is not usually and 'end', unless it is already accomplished, or very final, or you are in a Sherlock Holmes-era novel.

You can get away with "toward this end".  But please do not use "towards" here.  In the U.S. "towards" is dying, and it will be heard as something more concrete.  If you say "towards this end", I, (and a lot of Americans), think "Which end, the right or the left?" before I get to the idiom.

Comment: I thought "towards" was british while "toward" was american... thx

Comment: Sorry, yeah, either is correct, especially in Britain, but 'towards' is dying in the US, and in general it is less well understood in more abstract contexts.

Comment: Would "towards this goal" sound better?

Comment: No, it sounds better with end.  Just don't say something more specific than you mean.  If the goal is really specific, or is already attained, exactly what you said is just fine.

If I were going for a different formulation, it would not be a variation on this turn of phrase, it might be "on this goal" or "in this area".